# On-device speech recognition not working for Pixel 3/3A

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech

I am creating an android app that uses API 31 [on-device speech recognition.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer#createOnDeviceSpeechRecognizer(android.content.Context)) The app works fine on Pixel 6, 5 and 4 if the device is set to en-US locale but not on Pixel 3 and 3A.

The logcat shows:

```
2022-02-14 16:26:09.712 3794-3794/? I/RecognitionServiceImpl: RecognitionService#onStartListening
2022-02-14 16:26:09.713 3794-3794/? I/IntentParsingUtil: Using Locale.getDefault() for recognition: null
2022-02-14 16:26:09.713 3794-3794/? I/AiAiSpeechRecognition: [AiAi RecognitionService] session start logged
2022-02-14 16:26:09.713 3794-3794/? I/IntentParsingUtil: Using Locale.getDefault() for recognition: null
2022-02-14 16:26:09.714 3794-3794/? I/IntentParsingUtil: Using Locale.getDefault() for recognition: null
2022-02-14 16:26:09.714 3794-3794/? I/AiAiSpeechRecognition: [AiAi RecognitionService] prefer offline logged
2022-02-14 16:26:09.715 3794-3794/? I/SodaSpeechRecognizer: Offline recognizer - start listening
2022-02-14 16:26:09.715 3794-4076/? I/AiAiAudio: #startListening
2022-02-14 16:26:09.727 1198-12869/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0x7410859c60 tid=12869 ready to run
2022-02-14 16:26:09.733 3794-8144/? I/AiAiAudio: run(): Tee read loop starting
2022-02-14 16:26:09.736 3794-4110/? E/native: E0214 16:26:09.736452    4110 language_pack_utils.cc:346] No usable config found in LP at: /data/user/0/com.google.android.as/files/superpacks/speech-recognition/aiai_en_us_v27
2022-02-14 16:26:09.736 3794-4110/? E/native: E0214 16:26:09.736668    4110 soda_impl.cc:524] Terse enabled but could not initialize processor: Terse Processor: No usable config found in LP.
2022-02-14 16:26:09.739 3794-4110/? I/SodaDetectionHandler: Initialized SODA with status: 5
```

The only difference I've noticed is that the English US language pack downloaded in **Pixel 3/3A is only 79MB and is version v3006** while the one on the other Pixel devices is **325 MB and v7017.**

Could this be related? It seems like from the logcat,
`language_pack_utils.cc:346] No usable config found in LP at: /data/user/0/com.google.android.as/files/superpacks/speech-recognition/aiai_en_us_v27`
the speech recognizer can't find the language pack for english US even if en-US is downloaded already. Maybe it needs to be updated but I can't find a way to do so.

Comment: Possibly related on Google Issue Tracker: [On-device speech recognition stopped working on Pixel 4 and 5 but works on Pixel 6](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/226094999)